# fast forwarding a song using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am creating an audio player application, i need to enable the user to fast forward and backward a song by holding a button(seperately for each). I've done for playing, stopping, skip to next and previous song. But i got stuck with this section. I dont know the method to implement this. pls help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `currentTime` and `duration` properties.

i.e. to skip forward

```
NSTimeInterval time = avPlayer.currentTime;
time += 5.0; // forward 5 secs
if (time > avPLayer.duration)
{
    // stop, track skip or whatever you want
}
else
    avPLayer.currentTime = time;
```

Similar for going backwards, only compare `currentTime` against `0`, instead of `duration`

Answer (score 2):

In swift 4

for forward

```
var timeForward = audioPlayer.currentTime
        timeForward += 10.0 // forward 10 secs
        if (timeForward > audioPlayer.duration) {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = timeForward
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = audioPlayer.duration
        }
```

for backward

```
var timeBack = audioPlayer.currentTime
        timeBack -= 10.0 //backward 10 secs
        if (timeBack > 0) {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = timeBack
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
        }
```

Hope this will help.