# AudioPlayer fast Forward in Xcode

Tags: ios, audio

Is there a way to fast forward an audio file by x2, x4 etc by the use of a button? If not, do you have any idea how this would be possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478472/fast-rewind-fast-forward-in-avaudioplayer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921208/fast-forwarding-a-song-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: before ask a question try to google it or search it in SO.

Comment: ok thanks.. I did google but I guess I did not searched enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval *timeIntervel = [yourPlayer currentTime];
timeIntervel = timeIntervel + timeToForword;
[yourPlayer setCurrentTime:timeIntervel];    
[yourPlayer play];
```

Comment: is there a way to make it play faster without skipping seconds? (tempo/pitch "regulator")