# How do I fastforward using AVAudioplayer while hearing the music?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I got it to fast forward but I would like to hear the music when its fast forwarding. How would I be able to do this? Here is the code I have:

```
if node.name == "left" {

            var time = musicPlayer.currentTime
            time += 1.0
            musicPlayer.enableRate = true
            musicPlayer.rate = 2.0


            if time > musicPlayer.duration {

            } else {
                musicPlayer.currentTime = time
     }
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921208/fast-forwarding-a-song-using-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`rate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/rate) property on `AVAudioPlayer`

> This property’s default value of 1.0 provides normal playback rate. The available range is from 0.5 for half-speed playback through 2.0 for double-speed playback.
>
> To set an audio player’s playback rate, you must first enable rate adjustment as described in the enableRate property description.

You could change the rate for a certain amount of time when a button is pressed to simulate fast-forwarding

Comment: I added that to my code but still dont hear anything when Im fast forwarding. I updated the code in the op, can you take a look at it?

Comment: Im getting this weird thing happedning when Im using rate. I have this slider for the song and when I move it and let go it fastforwards. When i try it with my button it doesnt fast forward.

Comment: How would I rewind using rate property? I got the fastforward to work but cant figure out how to rewind.

Comment: @coding22 knew you'd figure it out :) - for rewind, try setting the rate to a negative number as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

Comment: I tried setting it to -2.0 but its not working for me.

Comment: On that documentation it talk about items being able to play in reverse - do the two methods it mentions to check for this return true?

Comment: I can't use that property because my musicPlayer is an AVAudioPlayer not an item.