# Is there a way to rewind music using rate property in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer

I'm fast forwarding my `AVAudioPlayer` by setting the `rate` value. However I can't figure out how to rewind.

I'm making a DJ app, where the music's play `rate` changes upon spinning the turntable, causing the music to fast forward and rewind (while still hearing the sound).

This is my current method for the turntable spinning. How can I rewind the `AVAudioPlayer`?

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


    //this is for the left turntable
    if node.name == "lefttt" {

        //lets user rotate left turntable when there is one finger on turntable.
        let dy = leftTurntable.position.y - location.y
        let dx = leftTurntable.position.x - location.x
        let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
        leftTurntable.zRotation = angle2


        let delta = (angle2 - previousAngle)
        if delta > 0 {

            // Code to rewind music goes here....
            print("rotateleft")


        } else {
            //This code works perfectly and fast forwards the music when spinning turntable to right
            print("rotateright")
            musicPlayer.rate = 2.0
            musicPlayer.play()
        }

        previousAngle = angle2
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 2.0 to musicPlayer.currentTime instead of substraction? Maybe it starts counting down from the remaining time.

Comment: Yes I tried adding and it still fast forwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewind by setting the `currentTime` to a value smaller than its current value.

I don't think this will rewind in some *audible* way. You are not going to magically hear the music run backwards or anything like that. AVAudioPlayer doesn't do that. It will, however, change the play position so that when you start playing again (forwards) you'll start earlier than where you were.

AVPlayer (as opposed to AVAudioPlayer) can play in reverse, but only if the particular AVPlayerItem permits it.

Comment: What I'm telling you turns out to be basically the same information you were given on your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587401/how-do-i-fastforward-using-avaudioplayer-while-hearing-the-music Instead of asking the same question multiple times, try listening to the answer you're given.

Comment: This question is about rewinding, not fast forwarding. This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587401/how-do-i-fastforward-using-avaudioplayer-while-hearing-the-music. OP obviously knows how to fast forward (as per the included `touchesMoved` method)

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi It is a duplicate because he has already been told he can't play backwards with an AVAudioPlayer. He keeps asking the same question because he doesn't accept this fact.

Comment: I see now that OP has posted this question one too many times. However, the question is still not a duplicate and should be marked as closed, not duplicate.